# prog.java:52: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean for(int i=0;i=n/2;i++){

Tags: java, arrays, reversing

Does values in for loop gives boolean results in Java?
Getting this error when I compiled the code:

> prog.java:52: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean
> for(int i=0;i=n/2;i++){

```
public static void reverseArray(int arr[], int n) {
    // Your code here
    
        int temp;
        int i=0;
        for(i=0;i=n/2;i++){
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[n-i];
            arr[n-i]=temp;
        }

    }
```

Comment: The `termination` portion of your loop is the issue: `i = n/2` is not a boolean expression.  So describe how you want to terminate the loop ; is it `i < n/2` ?  For clarity: `When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.`

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 5
 at Get.reverseArray(File.java:45)
 at Driver.main(File.java:25)

Comment: public static void reverseArray(int arr[], int n) {
        // Your code here
        
            int end=n-1;
            for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
                int temp=0;
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[end];
                arr[end]=temp;
                end--;
                
            }
    
        }

Comment: Please don't post code or errors in comments, it's very hard to read. Update your *question* with that code and format so it's readable. Also, n = ???

Answer (score 1):

1. The second parameter of `for` loop needs to be fixed to provide boolean expression: `i < n/2`
2. When swapping elements, the index of the last element is `n - i - 1` as the array indexes in Java are zero-based: `[0..n - 1]` make `n` elements.

Thus, the updated function may loo like this (with all relevant variable declarations moved inside `for` loop):

```java
public static void reverseArray(int[] arr, int n) {
    for (int i = 0, j = n - 1; i < n/2; i++, j--) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

---

Also, the implemented method allows to reverse *a part of `n` elements* of the input array, so it may be better to have an overloaded version accepting only `arr` argument, and use minimal value of `n` and `arr.length` to prevent `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```java
public static void reverseArray(int[] arr) {
    reverseArray(arr, arr.length);
}

public static void reverseArray(int[] arr, int n) {
    for (int i = 0, m = Math.min(n, arr.length), j = m - 1; i < m/2; i++, j--) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Test:

```java
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
      
reverseArray(arr, 3);

System.out.println("After reverse: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output:

```
After reverse: [3, 2, 1, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The problem is resolved.